# How to avoid grand_parent id in 2 level nested routes in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4.2, ruby-2.1

I my routes file:

```
resources :users do 
  resources :posts, shallow: true do
    resources :comments, shallow: true
  end
end
```

Now, routes for comments for index seems like below :-

```
"/users/:user_id/posts/:post_id/comments"
```

Now, I would like to get only below type url:-

```
"/posts/:post_id/comments"
```

ie. I would like to skip the grand_parent portion. How can I achieve this, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simply putting shallow: true option in grand_parent gave the solution as:

```
resources :users, shallow: true do
  resources :posts do
    resources :comments  
  end
end
```